# how to pass the value from Jquery to jsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

My jQuery code:

```
function check_availability(){   

         //get the username   
         alert("hai");
         var result ="";
         var CompanyCode = $('#CompanyCode').val();   
     alert("Jquery " +CompanyCode);
     //use ajax to run the check   
         $.post("checkUserName.jsp", { CompanyCode: CompanyCode },   
             function(result){   
                 //if the result is 1   
                 alert("result"+result);
                 if(result == 1){   
                     //show that the username is available   
                     $('#username_availability_result').html(CompanyCode + ' is Available');   
                 }else{   
                     //show that the username is NOT available   
                     $('#username_availability_result').html(CompanyCode + ' is not Available');   
                 }   
         });   

}
```

checkUserName.jsp:

```
String companyCode = request.getParameter("CompanyCode");
out.println("companyCode"+companyCode);
```

```
rs = dbAccess.executeQuery("select companycode from yosemitecompany where companycode = '"+companyCode+"'");
```

How to get the values from jQuery? I need to get the answer in the JSP page for checking ,whether the record is present or not in the table. I am not getting the value from the `request.getParamater() method`. Is this any other way to check that ?

Comment: @adal arasan you can not get from request.getParameter() , its not a server call right.

Comment: ok .how to get the values from it.After i get the values am checking with the database whether it's present or not.so am using the jsp page for process the data.Is it correct or not ?

Comment: @adal sorry , is that how you get querystring in jsp , i am from .net background , we use request.querystring///

Comment: @adal,finally what happened is it working , you can check in net panel of firebug

Comment: gov,i need ur help..it's still not working...am in the deadline...can u help me..

Comment: @adal , lets debug , do you firefox and firebug instaleld , if so open net panel in firebug and do a post ,it showz all the ajax calls , and then verify if your querystring is going or not.

Comment: @adal if this didn't work why don't you use sime ajax instead of post $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
}); once this works , you can change later to..post

Comment: @adal ,do you need any help?? i am going to logout

Comment: can you send me the $.ajax coding instead of $.post ..After 45 minutes i will reply you.Am going to take a lunch

Comment: gov, do u have that $.ajax code instead of $.post

Comment: @AdalArasan - I can't tell from reading this what is happening, exactly which part doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
     $.post("checkUserName.jsp", { CompanyCode: CompanyCode },
```

Try

```
     $.post("checkUserName.jsp", { Code: CompanyCode },
```

Perhaps it's an issue with naming the keys the same as that var...

Comment: Thankx.Then i will use code or CompanyCode to get the value in jsp

Comment: hi hank .i tried that but it 's not working,any other way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely valid. Only thing as said above the variable naming may the issue. 
You can try the other option from jquery api,

$.post("checkUserName.jsp", $('#CompanyCode').serialize(),..

This should take care of your issue. Because query string values should be quoted ('') properly. This serialize method would take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CompanyCode is the  id attribute.So just create an attribute **name="something"**
then use request.getParameter("something").I hope it will work